# Transition on dynamically created HTML5 element.. How to define in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, transition

I am creating a new `<div>` through the `onclick` method of a button. The idea is that a Card appears on screen that can then be handled by a number of actions. The HTML5 code for the button is the following.

```
<input type="submit" class="transition_submit" value="Transition" onclick="card_AppearsHome()">
```

In order to dynamically create the card, I added a JavaScript file. I use a variable `transition_counter` to track the state of the card, similar to "show/ hide".

```
function card_AppearsHome() {    

if (transition_counter == 1){

    document.getElementById("white_background_top").removeChild(home_card);
    transition_counter = 0;
}

else {

    //card/ div is created and appears, need to select a tranform: transition method 
    //probeer hier JQuery te gebruiken, dit is veel minder code 
    home_card = document.createElement('div');
    home_card.id = "home_card";
    home_card.style.position = "relative";
    home_card.style.width = "20vw";
    home_card.style.height = "20vh";
    home_card.style.left = "54vw";
    home_card.style.top = "25vh";
    home_card.style.background = "#000";
    document.getElementById("white_background_top").appendChild(home_card);

    transition_counter = 1;
}
}
```

This creates and removes the card through clicking on the button. What I want to do now is to define incoming and outgoing transition effects to the card. I have some difficulties finding documentation on how to define these transition effects in a JavaScript file on a newly created element.

What should I do?

If you can just point me in the right direction, the effect is not important right know, I just need to know how to access transition method from here on..

Comment: You're aware that [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) is a CSS property...so ex. `home_card.style.transition = "1s"` is the most simplest way to assign it via JavaScript. Another more versatile way is by `.class` assignments.

Answer (score 2):

By incoming and outgoing transition effects, do you mean like an animation where it slides in and then slides out?

If so, you can probably use primarily CSS for that.
Possible documentation: [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) & Using it in [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transition.asp) (look in the left bar, there are more pages. I just linked the two main ones)

---

You could also look into just CSS animations and then just invoke the animation via JavaScript whenever it is created and closed out.
Documentation for CSS Animations [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

And to invoke the animation you should be able to just add a class to the object and it will then carry out the animation, and then remove the class later when animation is fulfilled.

Sorry for no code examples, I am currently not home. If you need some I can probably try creating a JSFiddle or something for you when I am able to.

Answer (score 1):

I used the ClassName solution to solve the problem and moved most of the style code to CSS. So the new Javascript code is..

```
function card_AppearsHome() {


if (transition_counter == 1){

    document.getElementById("white_background_top").removeChild(home_card);
    transition_counter = 0;
}

else {

    //card/ div is created and appears, need to select a tranform: transition method 
    home_card = document.createElement('div');
    home_card.id = "home_card";
    home_card.className = "homecard_appear"

    console.log(home_card.id);

    document.getElementById("white_background_top").appendChild(home_card);

    transition_counter = 1;
}
}
```

My code in CSS is the following.. I also added an entry animation to it, just to test this..

```
/* Markup for the card created dynamically */
#home_card{
position : relative;
width: 20vw;
height : 20vh;
left : 54vw;
top : 25vh;
background-color: #000;
}

/* card appearing effect */
.homecard_appear{
animation-name: card_appear;
animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* standard transition */
@keyframes card_appear {
from {left: 54vw;}
to {left: 94vw;}
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 transition */
@-webkit-keyframes card_appear {
from {left: 54vw;}
to {left: 94vw;}
}
```

Thank you for your help!